# How to hide or rename “X” and “x-child” references in website source?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

We have been asked us to hide/rename the “x” and “x-child” references in our website source, and generally the entire WordPress (wp-content) folders. In particular is it possible for me to rename or “hide” the following folders, in particular reference to “x”:

```
<link rel=’stylesheet’ id=’x-stack-css’ href=’example.com/wp-content/themes/x/framework/css/site/stacks/integrity-light.css’ type=’text/css’ media=’all’ />
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’example.com/wp-content/themes/x-child/js/custom-scripts.js’></script>
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’example.com/wp-content/themes/x-child/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js’></script>
<script type=’text/javascript’ src=’example.com/wp-content/themes/x/framework/js/dist/site/x-head.min.js’></script>
```

We use X theme Integrity version. 
The X theme doesn’t provide any extension with the ability to get this thing done.

Does anyone have the solution for the above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

In the child theme style.css file, change the following info:

Theme Name: **X Child Theme**
Theme URI: **http://theme.co/x/**
Author: **Themeco**
Author URI: http://theme.co/
Description: **Make all of your modifications to X in this child theme.**
Version: **1.0.0**
Template: x

Change the Bold items above to whatever you want, just make sure to keep the Template reference as is.

You can also change the screenshot.png file in your child theme folder to reflect an image you'd like to display, should someone look up what wordpress theme you are using- with a website like whatwpthemeisthat.com or something similar.